# How to implement a simple cube in WebGL without using any libraries as glMatrix and etc?

Tags: javascript, graphics, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, sample

I was learning three.js, and this library is awesome, it simplifies my development process. But today I want to start learn plain WebGL just for better understanding, and I want to implement the basic samples from the scratch without using any already done JavaScript library such as glMatrix, sylvester, j3di and etc...

I've tried to search in web some plain examples, but any sample, which is close to plain (I mean "without using any additional libs" in this context) uses some libraries.

Of course, library use is very good when you're developing a product to economy your time, but my aim today is different, I just want understand how to make planes, cubes and other in WebGL from scratch just for well understanding.

I'm asking for such samples, because even in MDN or Khronos official wiki there are suggestions to use libraries:

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Creating_3D_objects_using_WebGL (sylvester.js, glUtils.js)
- Khronos: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial (webgl-utils3d.js, J3DI.js)

So can you help me with showing some WebGL sample with cube or plane, which doesn't use any library.

Answer (score 3):

I think this Greggman's article covers everything you are looking for, and does not rely on any third-pary math library.

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-cameras/

http://greggman.github.io/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html